# React Native Animated Scroll view jump behavior

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Stuck with small problem. I have `Animated.ScrollView` and there i have onScroll Event like this

```
Animated.event(
                [
                  {
                    nativeEvent: {
                      contentOffset: {
                        x: this.topViewAnimation,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
                { useNativeDriver: true },
              )
```

So onScroll that card which active ( on the screen ) highlights `item` in view.

Sometimes i need to scroll to specific value with `scrollTo` method but i always see one problem.

For example i have 10 items. ( 10 items in view and 10 items which i will highlight based on scrollOffset ).

When i will use my `scrollTo` method i will see how every item highlights untill it become this one what i need.

Is there a way to highlight only one item what i need?

Answer (score -1):

I've just jumped into the same problem today, and after hours trying to solve this issue, the solution was quite straightforward.....

What I did is to NOT TO USE the Animated.ScrollView component, and instead, I **created a new ScrollView animated component** whith the animated interface:

```
const AnimatedScrollView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView)
```

Then I used this new **"AnimatedScrollView"** component insted of the **"Animated.ScrollView"** and everything run just smoothly...

Good luck!